# Running ssh-keygen without human interaction?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ssh-keys

Would it be possible to run **ssh-keygen** without human interaction?

I have a shell script that takes care of server deployment from start to finish, but ssh-keygen is the only remaining piece that still requires my input.

Would it be possible to feed the parameters to it?
Or is there something similar to *debconf-set-selections* that could be used for this?

*running Debian

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do more or less anything with command-line arguments. Is there something particular you want to do which doesn't appear in the man page?

```
wry@onyx:~$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -N "my passphrase" -C "test key" -f mykey
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in mykey.
Your public key has been saved in mykey.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
2f:17:a4:5d:6f:25:d7:5a:0e:84:be:af:ee:52:8b:42 test key
```

*(the rest snipped for brevity)*

Comment: Best to avoid storing this command in your history - you don't want the passphrase recorded in plaintext on your computer. (Yes, generally the history file has 600 permissions so only root could snoop, but better safe than sorry.)

Comment: The point is he's going to script it anyway.

Comment: In your script, use a prompt (`read -s`) to read the password to pass on. Also beware `ps` may reveal process command args (which will include password). Because of that it may be best to use `expect` along with the normal password prompt, to send it in that way.

Comment: It will still require human interaction if the file by that name already exists.

Comment: Recovering passwords from ssh keys is relatively trivial. In a world where many people use their admin workstation's login password as the key password it's better to advise people to NOT put a passphrase on keys. (protect your private key, if you fail to do that at least you don't also lose your password)

Answer (score 21):

In case of server deployment:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -q -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -N ""
```

In terms of communication from server installed to git repositories or other servers would be easy.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
operacao@ubuntu:~$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Comment: This does ask at least where to save the key.